# Why does UIUserNotificationType.None return true in the current settings when user permission is given?

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm writing a method to check if the current user settings consist of certain notification types.

When checking whether the current settings contain UIUserNotificationsType.None, it returns true for both when the permission was given and denied. Would anyone know why this is?

```
func registerForAllNotificationTypes()
{
    registerNotificationsForTypes([.Badge, .Alert, .Sound])
}

func registerNotificationsForTypes(types:UIUserNotificationType)
{
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes:types, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

func isRegisteredForAnyNotifications() -> Bool
{
    let currentSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
    print(currentSettings)
    print((currentSettings?.types.contains(.Alert))!)
    print((currentSettings?.types.contains(.Badge))!)
    print((currentSettings?.types.contains(.Sound))!)
    print((currentSettings?.types.contains(.None))!)

    return (currentSettings?.types.contains(.Alert))! //Just testing .Alert for now
}
```

When permission is on:

`Optional(<UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x7fabdb719360; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert UIUserNotificationTypeBadge UIUserNotificationTypeSound);>)
true
true
true
true`

When permission is off:

`Optional(<UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x7f96d9f52140; types: (none);>)
false
false
false
true`

Comment: I feel like it's behaving normally (given how it's implemented) but feels like a bug because of the misleading `.None`. If `.None` is ALWAYS true, then why do we have it to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

Funny thing, it just confirms that 0 contains 0 :)
Take a look on enum definition for UIUserNotificationsType:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIUserNotificationType

```
struct UIUserNotificationType : OptionSetType {
    init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
    static var None: UIUserNotificationType { get }
    static var Badge: UIUserNotificationType { get }
    static var Sound: UIUserNotificationType { get }
    static var Alert: UIUserNotificationType { get }
}
```

But it's more clearly visible in Objective-C:

```
typedef enum UIUserNotificationType : NSUInteger {
   UIUserNotificationTypeNone    = 0,
   UIUserNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0,
   UIUserNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1,
   UIUserNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2,
} UIUserNotificationType;
```

Comment: I get that. Yet in my head I expected that using the contains api alone will be enough to check whether the user has not given permission. I wonder if this is a known / accepted behavior